# Angular 2 form builder nested json can't iterate the object

Tags: json, angular, nested, formbuilder

I have json that looks like this:

```
{
"name": "", 
"effective_date": null, 
"expiry_date": null, 
"id": 1, 
"contacts": [
{
  "id": 1
}, 
{
  "id": 2
}, 
{
  "id": 4
}, 
{
  "id": 5
}
]}
```

And I'm trying to use that to populate a form.

Here are my controls:

```
        this.form = fb.group({
        'name': [''],
        'effective_date': [''],
        'expiry_date': [''],
        'id': [''],
        'contacts': fb.array([
          fb.group({
   'id': ['']
   })
   ])}]
```

Then in my Template I try to iterate through the contacts like this:

```
  <form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(form.value)" class="form-horizontal">
   ...
    <div formArrayName="contacts">
      <div *ngFor="let contact of form.controls.contacts.controls; let i=index">

          <div [formGroupName]="i">
              <div>
              <label>Contact ID</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="contacts" formControlName="id" placeholder="">
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
...
```

I do get an input on the screen for contact ID  but only 1 and I get an error in the console Cannot find form control at index 1. Also if I look at form.controls.contacts.controls.length I get 1, and not 4.   the examples I find are mostly nesting an array of strings.  How do I use form builder with nested objects?

Comment: Where are you receiving the JSON and why do you think your control is reflecting said JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I need to have a control in place for each object in the array.  I just had to add them with a loop like this :

```
  for (let entry of this.myJson.contacts) {
  const control = <FormArray>this.form.controls['contacts'];
  control.push(this.initContacts());
  }

  initContacts() {
    // initialize our contact
    return this._fb.group({
        id: ['']
    });
   }
```

before I set my form data

```
this.form.setValue(this.myJson);
```

BAM!